# Documentation of the lesser know AS3 properties

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Over the past three weeks, I have lost at least 120 man hours because of some lesser known functionality in ActionScript 3.  One of the problems was that, with Internet Explorer, if there are too many messages sent through LocalConnections, it will slow the messages sent through, but in the standalone player and in Firefox, this threshold is significantly higher.  Another was that the static values of a class are instantiated even if the member itself is not being used:

```
import path.to.FooClass;

private function thisIsNeverCalledButItEnsuresThatFooClassIsImported():void
{
    var f:FooClass = new FooClass();
}
```

Since FooClass had a static reference to a Singleton, that Singleton was instantiated so when I loaded a Module which used that Singleton, it would bind to values in an unpredictable way.

Additional cases where things behave in an unexpected way:

- MovieClip.addFrameScript
- flash.trace.Trace as a class
- int is a faster incrementer class, Number is faster for mathematics, and uint is incredibly slow.
- PrintDataGrid, if it has only one page, needs to have an empty value appended to the end of its dataProvider
- If you use try...catch around two LocalConnections and connect them to the same channel, you will force garbage collection without needing System.gc

So here's the question (and I'm sorry for omitting this in the original post), is there any consolidated documentation for this type of behavior anywhere?  Is there any (even non-Adobe) documentation on these issues (websites, forums, books, ANYTHING)?  I know that these things are definitely easy enough TO document, but has anyone done so?

If not, am I missing anything?  Are there other issues which I should know about?

Comment: Is there a question...or just a rant?

Comment: @Justin Niessner This is a legitimate question.  Are there any books out there which handle this stuff?  Websites?  Anything?  I feel like I keep getting caught with my pants around my ankles for things which definitely CAN be documented...

Comment: Please edit your Q to have a question inside it! At least, the question mark should appear somewhere in it... ;-)

Comment: http://www.learningactionscript3.com/ and other O'Reilly books about AS3 have been written together with Adobe. I haven't read them but if there's any printed information about these things, it would be in these books.

Comment: I've looked into the O'Rielly books, but this type of behavior is hard to find in them (and is often not present at all).  Normally they do not venture beyond Adobe's (often incomplete) documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure why people miss the question here, maybe it has been updated though. Upvote and favourite by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of useful information is very often not "centralized". Moreover, what you are looking for is something related to the experience of the programmer (more than to official docs).

Comment: I was afraid of that.  It seems, however, that with Flex, there needs to be more centralization than, say, with PHP, JavaScript or Java.  It is a shame that it does not exist.  Still, it is far better than JSFL, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there are two other methods for ensuring a class is included.

#1 - This syntax is actually used in the Flex source code:

```
import path.to.FooClass; FooClass; // note double reference

public class References
{
    // No references needed in this class
}
```

#2 - Use the [includes](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html) command line argument

```
-includes path.to.FooClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always submit your experience using the "feedback" section in the help.  Unfortunately, this is less obvious than the link that used to be at the bottom of each page in the older help files (which also served the useful function of opening a browser window with the web version of that help page).

Adobe says that it incorporates the comments from previous versions of the help into new versions, but my own observation suggests that there are instances where it does not happen.  However, that and the appropriate cookbook are still the best avenue for those who believe that this kind of information should be centralized.

Note that the whole purpose behind modules is to avoid compiling code multiple times, so importing FooClass kind of defeated the purpose.  The problems you had in this instance are just one of the many that happen if you use Singletons, and it's unfortunate that the first official Framework, Cairngorm, encouraged their widespread use.  Check out http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/ .